# Residue when computing $\int_{\gamma} \frac{\cos(z)}{z-1} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm stumbled upon a question when computing Residue.

I want to compute the integral $\int_{\gamma} \frac{\cos(z)}{z-1} dz$ with help of residue.

My solution is rather short since I can see directly that this has a pole of order 1 which gives me the residue $\cos(1)$ using the formula $$
\mathrm{Res}_{z_0} f(z) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{\mathrm{d}^{n-1}}{\mathrm{d}z^{n-1}} (z-z_0)^nf(z)
$$

However, in other exercises such as computing the integral $\int_{\gamma} \frac{\cos(z)}{z} dz$, I solved this with finding the coefficient $c_{-1}$, which I have problem with doing on the first integral since I don't see how the first factor $(z-1)$ would disappear in the Laurent series expansion.

Would anyone mind helping me out on how to do that? Or give me an hint?

Comment: I think the residue depends on $\gamma$. Could you give more information about how $\gamma$ is defined? If this curve has 1 inside, the integral can be computed using residue. If 1 is not inside $\gamma$, the integral is 0.

Comment: I would just use the Cauchy integral formula. If $\gamma$ encircles $1$, the value of the integral is $2\pi \mathrm{i}\cos(1)$.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I forgot to mention that $1$ is inside of $\gamma$.

Comment: Are you asking how to find the Laurent series of $\cos(z)/(z-1)$?

Comment: Yes, that's what im asking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't want to determine the Laurent series of the integrand in order to identify the coefficient $c_{-1}$, you can use the following formula for a pole of order $n$ of a function $f(z)$ at $z = z_0$ :
$$
\mathrm{Res}_{z_0} f(z) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{\mathrm{d}^{n-1}}{\mathrm{d}z^{n-1}} (z-z_0)^nf(z)
$$
You can check that it will "select" the desired coefficient $c_{-1}$ when considering the Laurent series $f(z) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=-n}^\infty c_kz^k$.

It is also to be noted that this formula doesn't work for an essential singularity (which is nothing else than a pole of infinite order), so that you still need to compute the Laurent expansion in that case.

---

**Edit** (see comments below) :

The Laurent series of $f(z) = \frac{\cos(z)}{z-1}$ around $z = 1$ is deduced from the Taylor expansion of cosine around the same point, as follows :
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{z-1} \sum_{k\ge0} \frac{cos^{(k)}(1)}{k!} (z-1)^k = \frac{\cos(1)}{z-1} - \sin(1) - \frac{1}{2}\cos(1)(z-1) + \ldots
$$
hence $c_{-1} = \cos(1)$.

Comment: Yes, that's the formula I used to compute the residue, but If I would like to solve is using Laurent series, how would you do so?

Comment: @uoiu  Sorry, I understood the question the other way. In that case, you need basically to find the Taylor series of $\cos z$ around $z=1$.

Comment: @uoiu  See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You have\begin{align}\frac{\cos(z)}{z-1}&=\frac{\cos\bigl((z-1)+1\bigr)}{z-1}\\&=\frac{\cos(z-1)\cos(1)-\sin(z-1)\sin(1)}{z-1}\\&=\cos(1)\frac{\cos(z-1)}{z-1}-\sin(1)\frac{\sin(z-1)}{z-1}\\&=\cos(1)\left(\frac1{z-1}-\frac12(z-1)+\frac1{4!}(z-1)^3+\cdots\right)+\\&{}\qquad-\sin(1)\left(1-\frac1{3!}(z-1)^2+\frac1{5!}(z-1)^4-\cdots\right)\\&=\frac{\cos(1)}{z-1}-\sin(1)-\frac{\cos(1)}2(z-1)+\frac{\sin(1)}{3!}(z-1)^2+\cdots\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You may find the Laurent series of $\frac{\cos(z)}{z-1}$ at $z=1$ (since the residue is at this point) by simply Taylor expanding the cosine, and then multiplying it by the factor of $(z-1)$. As a matter of fact, one of the standard methods of finding the Laurent series is to Taylor expand and then work from there :)

The expansion can be easily obtained by the Taylor series formula and is shown here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Taylor+expand+cos%28z%29+at+z%3D1

Now, multiply this series with $\frac1{z-1}$ and you see that the $z^{-1}$ term’s coefficient is simply the zeroth power Taylor term, which is $\cos(1)$.

Comment: Oh, now I see. I was confused with the $\frac{1}{z-1}$ if that made any difference when doing the expansion of $\cos$. But of course it is just the normal expansion at $=1$.This was the answer I needed to understand, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

It is also convenient to use *[Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry)* when doing the Laurent expansion to calculate the residue.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\mathrm{Res}_{z=1}\frac{\cos(z)}{z-1}}&=\mathrm{Res}_{z=1}\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\,\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}\right)\\
> &=\mathrm{Res}_{z=1}\left(\frac{1}{2(z-1)}\,\left(e^{i(z-1)}e^{i}+e^{-i(z-1)}e^{-i}\right)\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^i+e^{-i}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\cos(1)}
> \end{align*}

In (1) we just need to consider the constant term $1$ of the expansion of $e^{\pm i(z-1)}$.